# How can I filter <li>'s href value inside an UL depending on the value in a textbox?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="ulclass">
    <li><a href="#">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CCC</a></li>
</ul>

var textBoxValue = //value from textbox
$("ul#ulclass").find('li').filter(function() 
{
    if($(this).find("a").val() == textBoxValue)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}).css('background-color', 'red'); //optional
```

I'm basically trying to make a basic autocomplete feature. 
User writes `"A"` to the textbox, jQuery filters each `href text` between `<a>` and `</a>` to match, responses with a custom css styling but it's optional.

I'm stuck while filtering them. `filter` function has to be fixed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic example:

```
var $rows = $('#ulclass li');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    $rows.removeClass('active').filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return val && !!~text.indexOf(val);
    }).addClass('active');
});
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/QkMHB/1/

Answer (score 4):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) is for form inputs; anchors don't have values, but they do have [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text). Everything else about the code looks like it should work, though I can suggest some style improvements:

```
var textBoxValue = /* value from textbox */;
$("#ulclass").find('li').filter(function() 
{
    return $(this).find("a").text() === textBoxValue;
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

N.B. you may want to [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) the values when checking for equality, in case there is exta white space in the HTML or the user-provided string.

Answer (score 0):

Change this -

```
if($(this).find("a").val() == textBoxValue)
```

to this -

```
if($(this).find("a").text() == textBoxValue)
```

Anchor tags do not have values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="ulclass">
    <li><a href="#">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CCC</a></li>
</ul>

var textBoxValue = //value from textbox
$("#ulclass").find('li').filter(function() 
{
    return $(this).find('a').text().toLowerCase()==textBoxValue.toLowerCase();
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Remove toLowerCase if you want case sensative.
plus You can use id directly as they are unique.